# How to kill subprocess with a button

Tags: python, subprocess, raspberry-pi

I am using the open lighting architecture on a Raspberry Pi and I need to be able to start a show that runs in a constant loop with a button and kill that show and start another one with a button. I am using the pyface add-on with 4 buttons. I can start a process, but I cannot kill a process with the buttons.

If you are using ola in the command line you can stop the show by pressing control-c. I have been able to make a gui that can stop the process with tkinter but the same process doesn't work with physical buttons.

```
    from time import sleep
    import os
    import signal
    import piface.pfio as pfio
    import time
    import threading 
    from subprocess import Popen
    import subprocess
    import Queue

    pfio.init()
    pfio.digital_read(0)
    pfio.digital_read(1)
    pfio.digital_read(2)

    def olaserverStart ():
      os.system('olad -l 3')

    def show1():
        os.system('ola_recorder -p /home/pi/Mermaid -i 0')

    def stop():
        try:
            sig = signal.CTRL_C_EVENT
        except AttributeError:
            sig = signal.SIGINT
        send_signal(sig)

    def universe():
      global proc3
      proc3 = subprocess.Popen('ola_patch -d 12 -p 0 -u 0', shell=True)
      proc3.wait()

    def universe1():
        global proc4
        proc4 = subprocess.Popen('ola_patch -d 6 -p 0 -u 0', shell=True)
        proc4.wait()


    olaserverStart()
    universe()
    universe1()



  while True:
        if (pfio.digital_read(0) == 1):
                p3 = subprocess.Popen('ola_recorder -p /home/pi/Mermaid -i 0', shell=True)
                p3.wait()
        if (pfio.digital_read(1) == 1):
          try:
            sig = signal.CTRL_C_EVENT
          except AttributeError:
            sig = signal.SIGINT
          p3.send_signal(sig)
        if (pfio.digital_read(2) == 1):
                os.system('ola_recorder -p /home/pi/Mermaid -i 0')
        sleep(0.15);
```

Comment: related to the question title [start/stop subprocess using a tkinter button](https://gist.github.com/zed/4067619)

Answer (score 0):

when i  use the send_signal,it also doesn't work.I　don't know why.So i tried to use the os.kill to kill the subprocess.

```
pp = subprocess.Popen("ping www.google.com",stdin = subprocess.PIPE,stdout =            subprocess.PIPE,stderr = subprocess.PIPE,shell = True)
os.kill(pp.pid+1,signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: Have you tried both `p3.terminate()` and `p3.kill()` if the former doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

`p3.wait()` in your code blocks the loop until the child process ends. If you remove it then you could call:

```
if p.poll() is None:
   p.terminate()
   p.wait()
```

to terminate the process.

`os.system()` also blocks until the subprocess finishes. You could replace it with:

```
subprocess.Popen('ola_recorder -p /home/pi/Mermaid -i 0'.split())
```

that returns immediately as soon as `ola_recorder` launches without waiting for it to exit.

To avoid zombies you need to call `p.wait()` (blocks) or `p.poll()` (doesn't block). You should call the later until it returns non-None value (meaning that the subprocess exited).

Answer (score 0):

I tried again. It can terminate the process. When i do it like this

```
pp = subprocess.Popen("ping www.google.com", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout= subprocess.PIPE,stderr = subprocess.PIPE,shell = True)
```

It indeed has two processes. `/bin/sh -c` and `ping`. When i tried terminate(), it kills the `/bin/sh -c`. So the ping command is running still.

Comment: See [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279)